# Respond CMS image error

Tags: php, content-management-system

I've installed respond cms on my localhost using wamp. I followed the instructions and now it's installed correctly.

But, when I try to upload an image, it uses the wrong link on the page. It displays correctly on the admin side but doesn't in the main page.

Another issue is, when I try to use the image as a background, it has the correct url both on the admin and the main page.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Not from the information you have provided, I don't know anything about respond cms, but a quick suggestion would be to check the paths that the cms use to access the pictures for the front end?

Comment: @Hassan I don't know what code you are referring to. I'm using respond cms.

Comment: I know that it's a rather poor stopgap measure, but have you thought about using one of Respond's HTML components and trying to manually link the correct url that the admin side is using? Also, are you setting the background for just one page, or the entire site?